# Is there a way in form vaildation to check if a given date is in a certain range?

Tags: symfony

I got a field in my form were the user can put in his birth date. I would like to check (via the isValid()-method) wether this date is **in a certain range**. Is there a way to do that via the symfony build in functionalities (like as an annototation)? I thought about using *@Assert\Regex()* but i this would be quite a struggle i guess ..

Comment: Try to look in doc first. What parameters you have in standard date validator. But you question sounds like you need to create your own validator , http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: check this bundle https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXExtraValidatorBundle

Comment: Thank you. In fact I missed that part of the symfony cookbook .. I'll definitly catch up on that. Thanks also for the hint with the bundle, I'll check this out, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Symfony 2.6+ you can use the [Range Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/constraints/Range.html)

Copied from the docs:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Event.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Event
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Range(
     *      min = "first day of January",
     *      max = "first day of January next year"
     * )
     */
    protected $startDate;
}
```

> The minimum and maximum date of the range should be given as any date string accepted by the [DateTime constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)